# Questions about my simple Makefile

Tags: c++, makefile

Below is a copy of my Makefile. I have a couple of questions regarding it
My project is [here](http://www.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=g8466ce2e61e860d0999573474895b4c959d1f4510)

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -g

test:  car.o student.o   house.o main.o
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o test main.o car.o student.o house.o

main.o: student.h house.h    main.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c main.cpp

car.o: car.h

student.o: student.h car.h

house.o: house.h 

clean:
    rm -rf main.o car.o student.o house.o test
```

Now here are my questions:

Question 1:
I am a little confused regarding implicit Makefile rules.
Why does the Makefile work fine even if I replace

```
  main.o: student.h house.h    main.cpp
```

with this after doing a clean

```
  main.o: main.cpp
```

Could someone please clarify this .

Question 2:
Does it matter if the order of the dependency of `test` target changes (I tried a few and it doesnt). Confirmation from an expert would help.

```
test:  car.o student.o   house.o main.o
```

Question 3:
What happens when dependency are header files that have no commands under them such as this

```
student.o: student.h car.h
```

Update : 
After running make -p this is a part of what I got

```
house.o: house.cpp house.h
#  Implicit rule search has been done.
#  Implicit/static pattern stem: `house'
#  Last modified 2014-10-24 01:28:16.992760877
#  File has been updated.
#  Successfully updated.
# automatic
# @ := house.o
# automatic
# % := 
# automatic
# * := house
# automatic
# + := house.cpp house.h
# automatic
# | := 
# automatic
# < := house.cpp
# automatic
# ^ := house.cpp house.h
# automatic
# ? := house.cpp house.h
# variable set hash-table stats:
# Load=8/32=25%, Rehash=0, Collisions=2/20=10%
#  recipe to execute (built-in):
    $(COMPILE.cpp) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<
```

I am confused as to what it means

Answer (score 1):

You deleted your previous question about this matter; even though you weren't satisfied with its outcome, that experience could have been useful to another StackOverflow user. Please consider taking that question back online.

Question 1: The Makefile works fine because the dependences have not been updated. Remember that the Makefile serves the initial build as well as the subsequent rebuilds, speeding the latter up because it only looks at the files that have changed. In your example, you expressed initially that `main.o` depends on a couple header files. Then you removed both dependencies. In your software development cycle, your header files will be changed, and if the dependencies are not expressed at the next `make`, then the `main.o` will not be updated accordingly. This is a simple example, but it has a big impact in large software projects as object files are stuck in old versions.

Question 2: Not in small projects. On large projects, the first specified object file may contain a symbol that the second specified object file needs to be properly linked; so the full answer is: Not in small projects, but it's best to get used to it for future projects.

Question 3: Target order does not matter.

Question 4: The echo goes after the dependencies:

```
test:  car.o student.o   house.o main.o
    echo "This is the test"
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o test main.o car.o student.o house.o
```

Answer (score 1):

Run `make -p` to find out about the built-in rules and variables. In particular you'll get (amongst others)

```
COMPILE.cc = $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH) -c
COMPILE.cpp = $(COMPILE.cc)
OUTPUT_OPTION = -o $@
%.o: %.cc
#  recipe to execute (built-in):
    $(COMPILE.cc) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<
%.o: %.cpp
#  recipe to execute (built-in):
    $(COMPILE.cpp) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<
```

BTW, you could also use [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) (which is compatible with GNU make) as `remake -x`; it will show more what is happening and why.

With a recent GNU `make` (4.0 or better) you could also run `make --trace`

See also the [documentation of GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for the post. I just updated my post. Could you explain the last part of the update please. I am not sure what the variables $(COMPILE.cpp) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) are

Comment: Look into GNU make [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html) and use `remake -x`; as you can see `COMPILE.cpp` is the same as `COMPILE.cc`

Comment: I tried using `remake -x` and it said command not found so I had to `sudo yum install remake` After which when I do `remake -x Makefile` I get `Usage: remake [options] [target] ...`

Comment: Just run `remake -x` (without the `Makefile` argument) since `remake` is an improved clone of `make`

Comment: I still get `Usage: remake [options] [target] ...` do you think i installed the wrong remake or something ?