# Makefile doesn't clean object files

Tags: c, makefile

Here is the makefile:

```
OBJS    = main.o    hashFunction.o input.o list.o   list_inverted_index.o   memory.o    operations.o    sort.o
SOURCE  = main.c    hashFunction.c input.c list.c   list_inverted_index.c   memory.c    operations.c    sort.c
HEADER  = hashFunction.h input.h list.h list_inverted_index.h   memory.h    operations.h    sort.h
OUT     = myexe
CC  = gcc
FLAGS   = -g -c -Wall
# -g option enables debugging mode 
# -c flag generates object code for separate files

all: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -g $(OBJS) -o $(OUT)

# create/compile the individual files >>separately<< 
main.o: main.c
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) main.c

hashFunction.o: hashFunction.c
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) hashFunction.c

input.o: input.c
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) input.c

list.o: list.c
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) list.c

list_inverted_index.o: list_inverted_index.c
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) list_inverted_index.c

memory.o: memory.c
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) memory.c

operations.o: operations.c
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) operations.c

sort.o: sort.c
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) sort.c


# clean house
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(OUT)

# do a bit of accounting
count:
    wc $(SOURCE) $(HEADER)
```

I tried to append this `*.o` to the clean section (because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635453/how-to-include-clean-target-in-makefile) answer), but it didn't work.

Comment: The clean target is not automatically triggered.  You have to explicitly use it when needed:  `$ make clean`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not normally need or want to "clean object files".  The whole point of using Make, is that you don't clean up but stay dirty!

If you always want to clean everything up and start each build from scratch, then don't bother using Make, but write a shell script instead.

Comment: I agree with you in spirit, but every Makefile under the sun has a `clean` target—and for good reason :)

Comment: @RadonRosborough you misunderstood my point -  in fact, the GNU Make manual recommends to have a `clean` target. So we agree that all Makefiles probably have it.  My point was, that one should _not_ use it all the time, as a matter of habit.  The OP seems to want to always use it. In that case, better use shell script. Sometimes the best answer to "X does not work" is, in your situation, better don't use X and your problems will go away.

Answer (score 3):

I had to modify the makefile as such:

```
all: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -g $(OBJS) -o $(OUT)
    make clean
```

Answer (score 2):

You might lack a

```
.PHONY: all clean count
```

rule. The `.PHONY:` [target](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html) and rule should appear near the start of the `Makefile`, just after the variables definition (in your case, below the definition of `FLAGS`).
If you happen to have `all` or `clean` files (check with `ls -l clean all` in a terminal), you need to remove them using `rm`

You'll clean using `make clean` command.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26543313/841108) for useful hints (about `remake -x` & `make --trace`)

BTW, your `FLAGS`  should probably be `CFLAGS` (see output of `make -p`)

Read the [documentation of `make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html)

Comment: I put if after `FLAGS`, but it didn't get called! Why `CFLAGS` over `FLAGS`?